# Mixing Dictionaries With PostgreSQL Full Text Search

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a join query that I want to search posts as well as tags. However, I'd like the posts to be searched with the `english` dictionary that does stemming and the tags to be searched with an exact `simple` match. Is this possible?

For example:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(
  SELECT posts.*, 
     setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(title, '')), 'A') || 
     setweight(to_tsvector('english', coalesce(body, '')), 'B') || 
     setweight(to_tsvector('simple', coalesce((string_agg(tags.name, ' ')), '')), 'B') AS document 

     FROM "posts" 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "posts_tags" ON "posts_tags"."post_id" = "posts"."id" 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN "tags" ON "tags"."id" = "posts_tags"."tag_id" 

     GROUP BY posts.id
) p_search

WHERE (document @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'sometag'))
```

I want to search `posts.title`, `posts.body`, and `tags.name`, they are all strings.

Comment: Sure, just specify two `WHERE` conditions.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe So adding something like `OR (document @@ plainto_tsquery('simple', 'sometag'))`

Comment: I can't say. Your query leaves me clueless. What columns in `posts` and `tags` do you need to search? What is their data type?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I want to search `posts.title`, `posts.body`, and `tags.name`, they are all strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use different text search configurations in different parts of your `WHERE` clause, that is no problem:

```
WHERE to_tsvector('english', posts.title) @@ to_tsquery('english', 'something')
  AND to_tsvector('simple', tags.name) @@ to_tsquery('simple', 'mytag')
```

Comment: Will this significantly slow down the query?

Comment: That's a question that can only be answered by experiment.

Comment: Should this be `OR` instead of `AND`?

Comment: Perhaps. I just wrote an example of how it might work. You should adjust it to your needs.